# Error handling of PipelineModel.load(PATH) if path doesn't exist Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I want to do an error handling of PipelineModel.load(PATH) i.e want to check if path exists if it doesn't exist, I want to exit the code so was trying try except block but don't exactly know what the error I should be expecting, Below is the snippet for same

```
try:
    pipelineModel = PipelineModel.load(PATH)
except InvalidInputException:
    print('Path Does not exist')
    sys.exit(0)
```

Below is the error message 
 NameError: name 'InvalidInputException' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
    pipelineModel = PipelineModel.load(S3LOC)
except Exception as e:
    print('Exception Message ',e.args)
    print('Model is not deployed')
    sys.exit(0)
```

This snippet worked for me